# most derrived override

Tags: solidity

According to [solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#inheritance),

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract owned {
    function owned() public { owner = msg.sender; }
    address owner;
}

contract mortal is owned {
    function kill() public {
        if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}

contract Base1 is mortal {
    function kill() public { /* do cleanup 1 */ mortal.kill(); }
}

contract Base2 is mortal {
    function kill() public { /* do cleanup 2 */ mortal.kill(); }
}

contract Final is Base1, Base2 {
}
```

> > A call to Final.kill() will call Base2.kill as the most derived override, but this function will bypass Base1.kill, basically because it does not even know about Base1. The way around this is to use super:

My question is, `Final.kill()` will call `Base2.kill` because `Final` inherits `Base2` next to `Base1`? In other words, `Base2` comes after `Base1`?

If my understanding is correct, always the rightmost inherited contract is the most derived one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the solidity compiler [uses](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization) C3 linearization to resolve multiple inheritance. You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization).

In your case what happens is `Final` inherits `Base1` and requests `Base2` to override `Base1`.